# How to disable findstr from sorting output?

Tags: sorting, batch-file, findstr, alphabetical-sort

I'm piping output from a command to findstr to extract certain lines. Here's my code:

```
example_command.exe | findstr /C:"string_D  " /C:"string_B  " /C:"string_C  " /C:"string_A  "
```

Yes, there are two spaces after the string text.  I expected the output to be:

```
string_D
string_B
string_C
string_A
```

However, I'm getting:

```
string_A
string_B
string_C
string_D
```

findstr appears to be sorting the output alphabetically.  Can that be disabled?  I'd like it to output in the same order I entered it.

I want to do this with standard Windows 7 commands so I can easily distribute it in batch files.

I can separate the strings and run example_command.exe four times but that takes four times as long.

Is this another undocumented feature of findstr?

Comment: I think you'll find that `findstr` is returning the strings in the order they are in, in the command text.

Comment: I agree, try the command without findstr and see what order the lines appear in, findstr just takes a stream and outputs anything it is given that matches a pattern - and in the order it was given. ;)

Comment: Now that I look at it, you are correct, the original stream is alphabetical.  Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's pretty much running example_command.exe multiple times, this should give you the output you're looking for.

```
example_command.exe | findstr /C:"string_D  " && example_command.exe | findstr /C:"string_B  " && example_command.exe | findstr /C:"string_C  " && example_command.exe | findstr /C:"string_A  "
```

However like you said it will take 4 times as long.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to live with a little longer output time.  I'm also realizing I can output to a temporary file and then run findstr on it and then delete the temporary file.